When did Paul's letters become "orthodox" or widely accepted as such in Christian communities?
My impression is that Christ cults were pretty diverse in the first two centuries following Jesus' death, including Jewish and non-Jewish variations, as well as Roman and Eastern, but if Paul became authoritative early on, then I would have to change my views on the scope of that diversity.
It's obvious that once an ecclesiastical council determined that the letters officially belonged in the Bible, i.e, they were canonized, they became orthodox.  But there's a lot of room between general and official acceptance.

Can you expand your statement to include sources that show 1) the diversity and timeline and 2) that Paul was "ignored" early on such that the diversity blossomed?

Paul was writing to and correcting and exhorting churches long before there was a new testament Canon. Why are you equating canonization with authority?

How do you know they are canonized?

See my revised question.

All evidence suggests that Paul's letters were widely accepted as authoritative very early on, within the first century. He was almost certainly considered "orthodox" even within his lifetime.
Evidence with in the NT
The Council of Jerusalem (~ AD 48) affirmed Paul as a teacher of orthodoxy, at least as reported in Acts 15. The apostles Peter and James were both defended Paul at that time. Even if Luke's account of the Council is inaccurate, it shows a very early acceptance of Paul as orthodox, since the book of Acts was composed within the second half of the 1st century.
Given that Paul is the hero of the second half of Acts, any sect which considered Acts authoritative must also have considered Paul to be a great teacher of orthodoxy.
Probably the earliest work that clearly considers Paul's letters authoritative is the second epistle of Peter, which traditionally is ascribed to Peter and dated to the mid 60s. Many modern scholars doubt this attribution, but still usually date it to within the first century (though some date it to as late as 120~130). In any case, it is an early testament to the authority of Paul's letters, as 2 Peter 3:15-16 says:

And count the patience of our Lord as salvation, just as our beloved brother Paul also wrote to you according to the wisdom given him, as he does in all his letters when he speaks in them of these matters. There are some things in them that are hard to understand, which the ignorant and unstable twist to their own destruction, as they do the other Scriptures.

Here, Paul's letters are considered authoritative. Moreover, the author of this letter reports that even heretical sects considered Paul's letters authoritative at that time.
Proto-orthodox writers and Paul
The Apostolic Fathers also evidently considered Paul authoritative. There are too many examples to list all of them, but here are some sufficient to demonstrate the point:
Epistle of Polycarp to the Philippians (early 2nd century): Polycarp gives us, in the clearest terms imaginable, an affirmation of the authority of Paul's letters:

For neither I nor anyone like me can keep pace with the wisdom of the blessed and glorious Paul. When he was with you in the presence of the people of that time, he accurately and reliably taught the word concerning the truth. And when he was absent he wrote you letters; if you study them carefully, you will be able to build yourselves up in the faith that has been given to you. (Polycarp ad. Philippi 3:2, trans. by Michael Holmes. Emph. added.)

Polycarp also draws much of his phraseology directly from Paul. For instance, Poly.Phil. 1:3 says

Though you have not seen him, you believe in him with an inexpressible and glorious joy (which many desire to experience), knowing that by grace you have been saved, not because of works, but by the will of God through Jesus Christ.

This is evidently borrowing from Ephesians 2:1-10.
First Epistle of Clement (95 AD): Clement similarly affirms the authority of Paul's letters:

Take up the epistle of the blessed Paul the apostle. What did he first write to you in the beginning of the gospel? Truly he wrote to you in the Spirit about himself and Cephas and Apollos, because even then you had split into factions. (1 Clement 47:1-3)

Besides this, Clement sets forth Paul as an example of righteousness and endurance in 5:5-7, and makes myriad allusions to Paul's letters.
Letters of Ignatius (~110 AD): Ignatius clearly considered Paul orthodox and his letters authoritative. For example:

You are fellow initiates of Paul, who was sanctified, who was approved, who is deservedly blessed (Ignatius ad. Ephesus 12:2)


I do not give you orders like Peter and Paul: They were apostles, I am a convict; they were free, but I am even now still a slave. (Ign. Romans 4:3)

Ignatius also includes many near-quotations from Paul's letters, for example compare Ign. Eph. 8:2 with Romans 8:5,9

Those who belong to the flesh cannot do spiritual things, nor can those who are spiritual do fleshly things...Moreover, even those things that you do according to the flesh are in fact spiritual, for you do everything in Jesus Christ.

These and other examples attest to the fact that the church widely considered Paul's letters authoritative by the early 2nd century.
Heretical Sects and Paul
The authority of Paul was so widely believed that the oldest heterodox and heretical sects generally did not dispute it. The oldest group I could find that rejected Paul's authority is the Ebionites. Little is known with certainty about the Ebionites. They are first clearly attested in the late 2nd century. Their own writings are not preserved, except in fragments, and they were not given much attention from proto-orthodox theologians. Irenaeus discusses them in Against Heresies I.26.2 and III.21.
Older and better-attested heretic groups all affirmed Paul as authoritative.
Gnosticism
Gnosticism, the oldest heretical sect (originating in the late 1st century AD), used Paul's writings extensively. Valentinus (2nd century) was one of the most prominent Gnostic theologians. He claimed to have been taught by Theudas, a disciple of Paul. The Treatise on the Resurrection (written by Valentinus or one of his disciples) quotes directly from 2nd Timothy 2:11-12 as an authoritative writing of "the Apostle":

Indeed, as the Apostle said, 'we suffered with him, and we arose with him, and we went to heaven with him.'

Additionally, many of the Gnostic works claim Pauline authority for themselves, e.g. The Prayer of the Apostle Paul or The Apocalypse of Paul. These works draw heavily on Paul's authentic letters.
Marcion (mid 2nd century)
One of the earliest and most well-known heretical teachers, Marcion of Sinope, went far beyond considering Paul authoritative--he considered Paul to be the only genuine Apostle. Marcion's entire canon consisted of one Gospel (now lost but thought to be an edited version of the Gospel of Luke) and ten Pauline epistles (nine in common with our NT, plus the now-lost Epistle to the Laodiceans; he did not include the Pastoral Epsitles).
Montanism (mid 2nd century)
Montanism was a movement with numerous parallels to modern Pentacostal and charismatic theology; it was founded by Montanus in the 2nd century and was widespread in the 2nd and 3rd centuries. Montanism was close enough to orthodox that theologians still dispute to this day whether it was correct to condemn it as heretical. Tertullian (3rd century), who was considered orthodox in his own day, defended Montanism, but it is unclear whether he actually joined the sect or not.
I could not find any direct evidence of the Montanists citing Paul. However, Tertullian often quoted from Paul as scripture. I do not think it's plausible that he would have accepted the Montanists as orthodox if they rejected Paul's authority.
Note on Canonicity of Paul's Letters
As you point out, including Paul's letters in the canon is tantamount to closing any debate on their authority. A canonical book is an absolute authority on orthodoxy--it is orthodox by definition. It is important to recognize, however, that declarations on the canon were not made arbitrarily. The Church only determined books to be canonical if they were already universally, or nearly universally, accepted as authoritative.
The earliest NT canon lists are those of Marcion and the Muratorian fragment, both dating to the mid 2nd century, and both include Paul's letters. But widespread discussions of the canon do not appear until the 4th century, at which time every proposed canon included Paul's letters. The controversial books of the NT were 2nd Peter, Jude, 2-3 John, and Revelation. Other than the aforementioned Ebionites, I know of no Christian sect (heretical or orthodox) that excluded Paul's letters from the canon until the 18th century Swedenborgianism, but even this considers them orthodox.
Justin Martyr, writing in about 150 AD, includes another possible reference to the canonicity of Paul's letters in chapter 67 of his First Apology, wherein he reports that "the memoirs of the apostles" are read in weekly church services alongside the OT scriptures. These memoirs may have included Paul's letters. While none of Justin's writings expressly reference Paul, scholars have noted some oblique references to Paul and some apparent influence in theology. Justin also does cite the Gospel of Luke; as mentioned above, if Luke-Acts is accepted as authoritative, Paul must also be at least considered orthodox.
Archaeological Evidence
While indirect, the fact that so many manuscripts of Paul's letters are preserved also indicates an early acceptance of them as authoritative. While most of the preserved ancient NT manuscripts come from after the 4th century when Paul was definitely considered canonical, there are also many 2nd and 3rd century manuscripts of Paul's letters, including Papyrus 46, which is a complete collection of Paul's letters except the pastoral epistles. This and other evidence suggests that collections of Paul's letters were already widely circulated by the start of the 3rd century.
Summary
Despite the diversity of sects in early Christianity, the acceptance of Paul's authority was nearly universal. There is no clear evidence of any Christian sect--even the heretical ones--doubting his authority until the late 2nd century. Granted, that is quite early, and the Ebionites may be far older than that. However, the lack of any earlier reference to them indicates that they were likely far less widespread or influential than the other Christian sects. The earliest and most reliable Christian sources attribute the highest authority to Paul.
Of course, we must acknowledge that all this evidence is fragmentary. There is not enough to persuade a determined skeptic. But the same may be said of any generally-accepted fact about ancient history. All the evidence that we have suggests that Paul was widely accepted as authoritative by the start of the 2nd century.

It's going to take me some time to review this answer. Thank you for providing it.
But  a question  pops up immediately:  To what extent can one rely on the authority of an orthodox writing in an authorized canon e.g., Acts, as evidence for the authority of the writings in that canon?  It's like relying on the authority as evidence of the authority.
I suppose that if I imagine that Acts were not part of the accepted Canon, that it were a first century document among all the others, to what extent could I rely on that document or any other as evidence for the authority of Paul?

Whether or not Acts is considered canonical, it is the earliest record we have about Paul beyond his own letters. So, you can take it as you would take any other 1st century document.

It is considered canonical right? It's part of the Catholic canon, yes?  But I agree with your point, I should probably divorce it from the New Testament and consider it as a historical document in its own right.

The fact of it being considered canonical actually should lend extra weight to its authority (at least, with regards to what the early church believed; questions of historical reliability are a different matter), since the church didn't declare things canon unless they were already widely accepted as authoritative. But at the very least, you should not dismiss it because it's considered canonical.

I cannot prove it, of course, but I have a theory that the known letters of Paul were gathered as a collection at a fairly early stage and were received as such by the churches.

That's the normal opinion among scholars, both secular and Christian.

@DarkMalthorp.  The reason I bring the question up is because I have heard other opinions concerning the heterodoxy of early Christian writings according to Walter Bauer.  The impression I'm getting from this is that there is controversy among scholars today about just how orthodox these early writings were.  Maybe the controversy is more specific? For example, maybe there's  not so much controversy about the authority of Paul but  still a lot of controversy about the gospels?

An immediate problem that comes up, one of my own making, is how to get a better handle on what constitutes "orthodoxy" in the sense of "widely accepted."  If I accept that Paul's first letter was written around 50 A.D., then the question would become how widespread were the Christian  sects at that time?  The fact that the first letter is to the Thessalians implies that it's already pretty widespread which then begs the next question, how representative are  the edicts of the Council at Antioch that you  referred to in Acts 15:1-31.  Did they speak for the majority of Christian communities?

The only real information we have about that are the NT, the Apostolic Fathers, and the Gnostic texts. All of these considered Paul authoritative, but the proto-orthodox and gnostic groups differed wildly in the interpretation of Paul.

There was undoubtably a great deal of diversity in pre-Nicene Christianity. However, the authority of Paul's letters seems to have been unquestioned, except by the Ebionites. There were other texts whose acceptance was more controversial, but the four gospels and the core Pauline epistles (i.e. non-pastoral) enjoyed close to universal acceptance from the earliest times. The controversies were largely about the interpretation of Paul and the Gospels, not about their authority.
